Manuscript in 'Decision in Process' for 6 weeks and no response to email requesting update
I seem to be having a recurring issue with a journal. I submitted a manuscript in April of this year that was sent out to peer-review and the reviews were completed relatively quickly. The manuscript then sat in 'Decision in Process' for 4 weeks before I sent an email politely requesting an update, after which within 2 hours I got the reviews back with a request to submit corrections within 3 weeks. I completed the corrections and submitted the updated manuscript. Again, the reviews were completed relatively quickly on the corrected manuscript and the manuscript then sat in 'Decision in Process' for another 4 weeks at which point I sent an email, again politely asking for an update. Unlike the previous time however, I have received no response to this request and it has been 2 weeks since I sent the email asking for an update on my manuscript following my corrections. Is it appropriate to send another email requesting an update? Or do I continue waiting? Is this unusual or am I unreasonable to think that these decisions following peer-review shouldn't take this long?

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/88355/is-my-paper-under-review-or-similar-for-too-long-and-if-yes-how-should-i-reac Does this answer your question?

One of the answers states that a decision is typically taken within a week, so I suppose it is not unreasonable of me to think that decisions shouldn't take this long once peer-review has been completed (which answers that question). However, what that thread does not address is whether it would be appropriate to send another email requesting update, after I have already requested one when the manuscript is in 'Decision in Process'.

This one, then? https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/26857/is-it-okay-to-resend-an-email-to-a-journal-asking-for-the-status-of-a-submitted

You can send an email, and you might get some information, but it is unlikely to change or shorten the decision process.
The canonical question on the editorial process provides some information, but there are a couple of other factors that can delay decisions.
If the editor handling your paper is not a full time employee of the journal, which is typical in some fields, their work for the journal must be balanced against other duties. Late Summer and early Fall can be busy periods for academics.
Moreover, if the journal is print, rather than online, then page limits for the currently planned issues must be taken into account, and if the more-or-less acceptable submissions exceed this limit there can be delays while the editor(s) work out the best use of available space, as well as, in some cases, providing some coherence to an individual issue.
I suggest emailing only if you have a need to know, rather than a desire to know. For example, if you have some decision pending or a deadline of sorts, then knowing might be necessary. Likewise if you are considering withdrawing the paper for any reason. Otherwise it is just anxiety producing. You can reduce that, perhaps by getting down (harder) to work on the next paper.

I guess I'm just anxious because I will be submitting my thesis within the next couple of months, and would like to have the paper (hopefully) accepted before then. Plus the need to factor in time for any further corrections while I write my thesis. Thanks for your response.

NGH, that probably qualifies as a need to know.
